# ¿Cómo filtrar objetos de un array?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola mi problema consiste en lo siguiente, tengo un array de objetos:

```
[
 {
  "id": 2,
  "nombre": "...",
  ...
  "finalizado":true
 },
 {
  "id": 6,
  "nombre": "...",
  ...
  "finalizado":false
 },
 ...
]
```

Para mostrar la lista completa utilizo un AsyncTask y muestro los items a través de una clase Adapter. Lo que necesito hacer es filtrar esta lista en base al campo ***finalizado*** descartando los que tienen como estado ***true*** y mostrar solamente los que vienen ***false***.

Para esto, sé que en el onPostExecute tengo que recorrer mi array e ir verificando en que estado me devuelven cada uno de los items:

```
JSONArray fullList;

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < fullList.length(); i++) {
                //if()
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Cómo debería preguntar por el campo finalizado? En el caso de ser false tengo que agregarlo a un nuevo array cierto? Podrian darme una ayuda con esto? Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tendrias que iterar sobre el `JSONArray` y por cada iteracion utilizas el metodo `getJSONObject(index)` y luego para obtener el valor boolean el  metodo [`getBoolean(name)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject elementoActual = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    boolean finalizado= elementoActual .getBoolean("finalizado");        
    if(finalizado)
    {
        // filtras el contenido
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria conveniente agregar los items a un nuevo JSONArray que ya tengo declarado globalmente así? `JSONArray filtered = new JSONArray()`. Ademas, es esta la forma correcta de agregar los items? `filtered.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));`

Comment: Lo mas conveniente seria crear tu propia clase que represente los datos que necesitas y lo agregas a una lista de ese tipo. Y sí, el metodo [JSONArray#put](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#put) es el metodo para agregar un nuevo elemento al `JSONArray`.

Comment: Entiendo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora tengo mas clara la situación!

Answer (score 4):

Podemos recuperar cada objeto para ver los valores

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    clave = object.getString("clave");        
}
```

Supongo que es esta https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 2):

Para consultar el campo "finalizado", tienes que crear un objeto JSonObject, crearlo y ya podrás consultar el estado

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSonObject js = jsonArray[i];
            if(!js.getBoolean("finalizado")){  //Comprobamos el valor del campo
                //Ahora lo añades al array que necesites
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Creo que es así, no he podido probar mi código

Answer (score 2):

Crea un objeto JSON y comprueba el valor del campo "finalizado".

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
        if (obj.getBoolean("finalizado") == true {
            //Lo que necesites
        }
    }
```